# Updating Clojure version for swank/slime

Tags: windows, clojure, slime, swank-clojure

I just updated from Clojure 1.2 to clojure 1.3.0 on Windows 7 
and emacs is still going to Clojure 1.2 with swank/slime.

Any suggestions where to change this so it uses 1.3?

Comment: what's your setup? Are you using swank-clojure? Are you using Lein or Cake? Do you have a specific Clojure jar listed in your .emacs or init.el?

Answer (score 3):

`lein deps` will fetch the clojure version you've declared in the `:dependencies` of your `project.clj`, and `lein swank` will start a swank server using that clojure version.

BTW: From inside emacs, I think it's more convenient to simply use `M-x clojure-jack-in` from a buffer associated with some file in your project.  That'll also start swank for you.

Answer (score 0):

use leiningen to start the swank server and it should get to to the correct version.

you also may need to re run `lein deps` after changing the version number if you are already using lein